# CSS: cascading on :hover?

Tags: html, css

Hey I have some styling to do but I'm not sure how to do it using regular css without js.

My html is like this:

```
    <div class="book">
        <span class="title">Snow Crash</span>
        <span class="author">Neal Stephenson</span>
    </div>
```

And my css is like this:

```
    div.book span.title { color: black; }
    div.book span.author { color: gray; }
    div.book:hover { color: orange; }
```

I want both the author and title to be orange whenever the div is hovered over, even though I have set them to be different colors normally. The spans won't inherit the color property from the div since they have their own colors set, and the hover of the spans won't activate unless you hover over the spans themselves. Can I do this without using javascript?

Comment: Doesn't `div.book:hover span.title { color: orange; }` work? Are you sure the div is positioned under it?

Comment: @Mark, you're completely right, div.book:hover span { color: orange; } works great, I was being thick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unless you really need to, you shouldn't specify the `div` in `div.class`. It just adds bloat to the CSS specificity. In some cases it makes sense (when you have a `span.title` and a `div.title` sort of issue).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
div.book span.title { color: black; }
div.book span.author { color: gray; }
div.book:hover, div.book:hover span.title, div.book:hover span.author
{
    color: orange; 
}
```

Comment: div.book:hover, div.book:hover span.title, div.book:hover span.author
{
    color: orange; 
}
can be re-written as: div.book:hover span.title, div.book:hover span.author {  color: orange; } to make it more concise.  The first div.book:hover is unnecessary.

Comment: most probably, but what if there is other text within the `div.book`? You're right though

Comment: you're right, it wouldn't style the other text in the div as orange on hover if you took that out.  I do like the :hover on the div itself better than my first thought.  That way it changes properly. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

The rule `div.book:hover` will not override `div.book span.title` and `div.book span.author` because the latter rules are more specific than the former.  You will need to do either:

```
div.book span.title { color: black; }
div.book span.author { color: gray; }
div.book span.author:hover, div.book span.title:hover { color: orange; }
```

or:

```
div.book span.title { color: black; }
div.book span.author { color: gray; }
div.book:hover { color: orange !important; }
```

I generally recommend against the use of `!important` unless it's absolutely necessary.

Additionally, I'd admonish that this is CSS3 and is only implemented in modern browser versions.

EDIT:
This is a third alternative:

```
div.book:hover span.title, div.book:hover span.author { color: orange; }
```